# Bootstrap dropdown not working in angular application

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, dropdown, popper.js

I have an angular application in which I want to use Bootstrap navbar with dropdown.
All styles from bootstrap are working just fine but the scripts are not workink e.g. dropdown not toggeling or on resize the toggle menu button not working.

I have installed bootstrap, jquery and popper.js and included them in
`angular.json` as follows:

```
"styles": [
   "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
   "src/styles.scss"
],

"scripts": [
   "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
   "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
]
```

I also tried importing scripts and css files directly into `index.html` but that also did not work.

I am copying HTML for dropdown navigation from [getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

Any ideas why the dropdown isn't working?

Comment: Look at the console, any errors?

Comment: Nothing in devtools console, nothing in angular console.

Answer (score 0):

I have just downgraded version of bootstrap from `^5.1.3` to `^4.6.1` and it works.
So I guess something changed in the latest version of bootstrap.